# How to format hidden input field in ftl/html

Tags: javascript, html, freemarker

I have to two fields type text in html, and two datepicker for those fields.
Now, when I choose the dates, they automatically populate text fields but in hidden input field those values are stored with the time also.

Like this:

value="2022-04-13T00:00:00+02:00"

Is there a way to format that input to be like this:

value="2022-04-13"

Thanks in advance...

Comment: supposing you are populating the hidden input value with javascript, you could transform that data using a substring like `"2022-04-13T00:00:00+02:00".substring(0, 10)`

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using?
in this code example everything works as you expected.

```
 <input id="date" type="date"  />
    <input id="hidden" type="hidden"  />
    <script>
      const date = document.querySelector("#date");
      const hidden = document.querySelector("#hidden");
      date.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
        hidden.value = date.value;
      });
    </script>
```